# Design pattern for Viewmodel change triggering another viewmodel change?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application, I have several models and viewmodels. Consider an example:

The `SurfaceCondition` property of my `RoadViewmodel` changes. I want this to (asynchronously) trigger a change of the `Wheel` property of my `CarViewmodel`.

I can think of several solutions, but I sense this particular problem has a well-recognized solution. Using messages? Putting a reference in the RoadViewmodel to the `CarViewmodel` and trigger an update through the property? Merging the viewmodels? WPF gurus out there, please enlighten me!

Comment: definitely not the two last solutions you propose as they violate Seperation of Concerns / DRY principles. Messages seems like a fine, decoupled solution though.

Comment: Point me to a good source for an implementation of some message pattern and I'll accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the two last solutions you propose as they violate Seperation Of Concerns (RoadViewModel knowing about CarViewModel) / DRY principles (RoadViewModel having to update CarViewModel or merging two classes).

Messages on the other hand seems like a fine, decoupled solution here. There are a couple of implementations available, for example [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) has en `EventAggregator` class, [MVVM Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) has `MessageBus` etc. Or search for terms like 'MVVM event bus'. Now whatever you choose, know that it is always good to not use those classes directly but instead pass an interface. For example with Prism, you'd program your viewmodels to use the `IEventAggregator` interface only. In the actual application you pass them an instance of the actual EventAggregator, whereas during unit tests you pass the a mock.

Comment: EventAggregator from Prism for publishing and subscribing to events works / message, or the other option is to implement a "Controller" that is responsible for creating views/viewmodels and sometimes handling events or communication between them.